# changing a html select value with jQuery does not reflect on screen display

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote two jquery plugins: the first converts a text or hidden input containing a date in a set of three drop down menus with day/month/year choice.
The second plugin allows me to generate a set of rows starting from a set of input fields, and automatically adds a "Add row" button and a "delete row" button.
Moreover, I've added a addRow() function to the "multiple row plugin", which allows me to add a row programmatically.

In this way I can do a call to

```
$(...).addRow(["event name", "30/06/2013"]);
```

to add a new row to my list.

Here is a simplified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gB2Dq/

The problem is that the value of the input field containing the event name is updated correctly, whereas the selected value in the drop down menu is not updated.
I think there is some stuff in dddtpicker plugin which breaks the DOM, but I can't figure out why.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that `id` must be unique across all elements on the page. You have several elements with the same `id`. Sorry, I'm not going to crawl through this to fix it though.

Comment: If that were the problem, the same should happen on the input type="text", which is replicated several times with the same id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var fields = templclone.find('input, select')`

There are 3 inputs and one select for each row which makes it 4 elements.

```
fields.each(function (index, element) {
    if (index < fields.length - 1) {
        $(element).val(args[index]).trigger('change');
...
myevt.addRow(["my event name", "30/06/2013"]);
```

You provide 2 arguments. So the `select` element gets the value `undefined`.

Comment: you got it. I have to stop assigning values when I have no more elements left in the args array:

Comment: the code becomes as following:
`if (index < fields.length - 1 && index < args.length) { 
   $(element).val(args[index]).trigger('change');}`